# mysql Remove some entries based on repetition set and Time

Tags: mysql

I am having 2 applications writing the input-Log location and output-Log location.
I want to have input and output Pair.

some times input-Log Location is updated twice but we should take the latest one only.

Example:

```
input_log x1 Time1
input_log X1 Time2
out_log   X1 Time3.
```

Here my table should be updated to remove input_log x1 Time1 because we need in table only input_log and out_putlog only for a given X1.
If the new input_log is after output_log we should not delete.

I was able to create a table , add time and sort with time.
I am having issue how to keep the condition so that those things will be removed.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(ID INTEGER ,Name TEXT,State TEXT,Timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT (STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'NOW')));


insert into MyTable (ID,Name,state) values (12,"name1","IN");
insert into MyTable (ID,Name,state) values (13,"name2","IN");
insert into MyTable (ID,Name,state) values (14,"name3","IN");
insert into MyTable (ID,Name,state) values (14,"name3","IN");
insert into MyTable (ID,Name,state) values (12,"name1","OUT");
insert into MyTable (ID,Name,state) values (13,"name2","OUT");
insert into MyTable (ID,Name,state) values (14,"name3","OUT");
```

Basically my application-process on bringup will update a log location (inlog).
and also update a exit log location (outlog). we dont want at the end of the day multipe inlogs (which happens some times when process is not started properly).

Comment: Where is `Timestamp` values in your example data ??? its absence do not allow to distinguish two records with `(14,"name3","IN")` values.

Comment: And MySQL do not know about `STRFTIME`. Maybe your DBMS is SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name, state 
                                        ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) rn
              FROM MyTable )
DELETE MyTable.*
FROM MyTable
JOIN cte USING (ID, Name, state)
WHERE cte.rn > 1;
```

For SQLite:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT ID, Name, state, Timestamp,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name, state 
                                        ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) rn
              FROM MyTable )
DELETE 
FROM MyTable
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM cte
               WHERE MyTable.ID = cte.ID
                 AND MyTable.Name = cte.Name
                 AND MyTable.state = cte.state
                 AND MyTable.Timestamp = cte.Timestamp
                 AND cte.rn > 1 );
```